# Verification of $\epsilon$-$\delta_\epsilon$ definition of continuity proof

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-verification

> Show that the function
>
> $$  f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{q},  & \text{if $x = \pm \frac{p}{q}$ in the lowest terms with $p, q \in N$} \\
> 0, & \text{if $x \in R - Q$}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> is continuous on $R - Q$ but is not continuous on $Q$.
>
> **Hint**: use negation of $\epsilon$-$\delta_\epsilon$ definition of continuity.

So I understand the $\epsilon$-$\delta_\epsilon$ definition of continuity and how to apply it to regular functions, but this was my first time attempting both the negation of the definition of continuity and for a piece-wise function.

**Continuous on $R-Q$**

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta_\epsilon > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|x - x_0| < \delta_\epsilon$

Take $\epsilon > 1$

$$|f(\frac{p}{q}) - f(x)| = |\frac{1}{q} - 0| = \frac{1}{q} < \epsilon$$

Take $\delta_\epsilon = \epsilon$ and we are done.

**Not Continuous of $Q$**

$\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall \delta_\epsilon> 0$ $|f(x) - f(x_0)| \ge \epsilon$ whenever$|x - x_0| < \delta_\epsilon$

Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2q}$

$$|f(\frac{p}{q}) - f(x)| = |\frac{1}{q} - 0| = \frac{1}{q} > \frac{1}{2q} = \epsilon$$

Take $\delta_\epsilon = \epsilon$ and we are done.

---

Side Question: When proving continuity for piece-wise functions you need to prove both (all) parts separately? This might be a dumb question, but I am not quite sure.

For example 
$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x < \sqrt 2$} \\
1, & \text{if $x > \sqrt 2$}
\end{cases}$

Comment: The continuity on $R- Q$ is not correct... you should use the fact that any sequence of rationals approximating an irrational has the denumerator going to $\infty$.

Comment: cf? @EmanuelePaolini

Comment: I changed $\epsilon-\delta$ to $\epsilon$-$\delta$.  Putting the "-" _inside_ the math tags results in a minus sign appearing instead of a hyphen.

Comment: Found the lemma, if $x_n = \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is a rational sequence that converges to an irrational number then $b_n \to \infty$, was this what you were talking about, @EmanuelePaolini?